# Percentage of radio stations that are terrestrial stations versus Internet stations

Tags: data-request, wikidata

What are the percentages of radio stations which provide:

- terrestrial radio station only
- Internet radio station
- both

I am looking into this data by year and world country. Thank you for your pointers.